# Remove last string from the output of my loop

Tags: c#

If I have the following program:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(i + " potato ");

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This will print out 
"1 potato 2 potato 3 potato 4 potato 5 potato"

How can I remove the last "potato" so it just says:
"1 potato 2 potato 3 potato 4 potato 5 "

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    Console.Write(i + (i != 5 ? " potato " : string.Empty));
}
```

Comment: This works, but could you walk me through what this is doing? `i != 5 ? " potato " : string.Empty`

Comment: Its the conditional operator ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)). Simply put: It is an if, just returning a value `<condition> ? <value when true> : <value when false>`

Comment: so "If i is not 5, print potato, otherwise, print nothing"?

Comment: Learned something new and it's the shortest solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
 var result = String.Join(" potato ", Enumerable.Range(1, 5));
```

If you need trailing space you can do:

```
var result  = String.Join(" potato ", Enumerable.Range(1, 5)) + " ";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
 {
    static void Main()
      {
       int max = 5;
        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
        {
          Console.Write(i);
          if(i!=max)   
            Console.Write(" potato ");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
       }
   }
}
```

Would do the trick.

Comment: I'm a beginner and I understand this the best out of all the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if( i < 5 )
                Console.Write(i + " potato ");
            else
                Console.Write(i);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This works and I understand it.  I don't know why it was down voted.

Answer (score 0):

Add a if check to determine if you are about to print the last record or not.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        int potatoCount = 5;
        for (int i = 1; i <= potatoCount; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i);
            //Only print 'Potato' when not on last print
            if (i+1 <= potatoCount) Console.Write(" potato ");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: prints 12345 potato.. that's not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Your right, that was a typo, sorry about that. Code fixed.